# Percona pt-online-schema-change failing to alter table

Tags: mysql, percona

I am trying to use the `pt-online-schema-change` to change the data size in a table. I am trying to increase the `name` column to `varchar(30)`

```
pt-online-schema-change D=clients,t=client_types --alter "CHANGE `name` `name` varchar(30)" --dry-run;
```

I am getting a few errors.

```
-bash: name: command not found
```

Then it seems like the command executes but ultimately fails.

```
Operation, tries, wait:
analyze_table, 10, 1
copy_rows, 10, 0.25
create_triggers, 10, 1
drop_triggers, 10, 1
swap_tables, 10, 1
update_foreign_keys, 10, 1
Starting a dry run.  `clients`.`client_types` will not be altered.  Specify --execute instead of --dry-run to alter the table.
Creating new table...
Created new table clients._client_types_new OK.
Altering new table...
2019-10-08T13:43:40 Dropping new table...
2019-10-08T13:43:40 Dropped new table OK.
Dry run complete.  `clients`.`client_types` was not altered.
Error altering new table `clients`.`_client_types_new`: DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(30)' at line 1 [for Statement "ALTER TABLE `clients`.`_client_types_new` CHANGE   varchar(30)"] at /usr/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 9194.
```

I am using `mysql Ver 14.14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my issue. `pt-online-schema-change --dry-run --alter "modify name varchar(30)" D=client,t=client_types;`